# Bootstrap icons nested in elements align wrong in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've noticed a small styling issue in one of my sites that use Bootstrap.  The issue only seems to happen in IE8 with a glyph icon nested in anchors/spans.

After struggling to solve this with CSS that didn't also mess up the popovers on the icons, I simply stopped wrapping my icons used for popovers and the problem went away.  The issue is easily reproducible by creating an anchor that contains the data attributes for a popover, and adding an `<i class="some-icon"></i>` inside the anchor.  It's more noticeable if it's on the same line as other text.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeades/TUDG7/5/)

** I can't seem to load jsfiddle in IE8 without it blowing up so you may have to recreate the fiddle locally.

If you add a non-breaking space or any text to the anchor, the icon aligns property with the text.  If the anchor/span only contains the icon, the icons vertical alignment seems to jump down.

I would still like to know how to solve the issue with css.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the work around I posted in the fiddle is the easiest solution to this problem.  If your using a single glyph icon inside of an anchor or span to trigger some type of popover in twitter bootstrap:

```
<a class="pop-me-over" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="This is some extra information." data-title="Information">
<i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
</a>
```

Simply add the popover data attributes to the `<i></i>` and remove the wrapping element.  This fixes the icon alignment issues in IE8.

```
<i class="pop-me-over icon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="top" data-content="This is some extra information." data-title="Information"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on nested spans inside anchors:

```
  span.label {
      display:inline;
      top:0px !important;
  }
```